# How to make our android app more secure, currently I'm using Algorithm for store data in Shared preference, It is okay for user security?

Tags: android, security, spring-security

Currently I'm using Algorithm to store data in Shared preference, It is okay for user security?. Below is the code,

```
private static SecretKey getSecretKey(Context context) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String secretKeyString = PreferenceUtils.getSharedPreferences(context).getString(PreferenceUtils.SECRET_KEY, null);
    if (secretKeyString != null) {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(secretKeyString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return new SecretKeySpec(bytes, AESEncryption.KEY_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM);
    } else {
        SecretKey secretKey = newSecretKey();
        secretKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        PreferenceUtils.getSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString(PreferenceUtils.SECRET_KEY, secretKeyString).commit();
        return secretKey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, its not safe to save sensitive data on shared preferences.Because Java code can be easily decompiled. C++ on the other hand can’t be decompiled but can be disassembled, which is slightly less trivial.So can store the static data like secret key, google api key or any other keys in c/c++ file using Android NDK. From here you can get the reference [Android NDK](https://androidsecurity.info/2016/12/15/storing-your-secure-information-in-the-ndk/)